# Hibernate - Copying Objects while checking if they exists first - performance slow - best approach?

Tags: performance, hibernate, ehcache, copying

I'm struggling with a performance issue for a copy feature that my application provides to the users.  I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way.  I don't have a lot of experience in Hibernate.

An over-simplified layout would be:

```
Project ---> (One to Many) Items ---> (One to Many) Tasks
Project ---> (One to Many) Variables
Items <---> Variables (Many to Many)
```

So, a project can have many items, and each item can have many tasks.  A project can have variables (no duplicates), and there is a many to many between items and variables (they are attached to one another).

There could be several hundred items per project, with several (20-30) tasks per item, and several hundred variables per project.  I added a function that allows users to check which items and tasks they want to copy from one project to another.  There cannot be any duplicates.

Here's the process I perform for each item that is checked:

1. Check to see if the item exists in the target project, if it does, add it, otherwise, don't.  I used the session.createFilter to query the target project (by item name).  If the item does not exist, I add it. (`object.save()`), and add it to the target project's items collection.
2. If the item has variables attached to it, I check the target project for those variables (again `session.createFilter()`), add them if they are not there, then add them to the item.variables collection

I'm not sure what, if anything, I can do to speed this up.  I'm assuming doing all the checks first isn't helping things.  I don't know if the createFilter is the best way for checking that items/variables exist in the target project.

I've tried changing the way the objects are added to collections.  I would add them each one at a time (`targetProject.add(item)`), now I'm storing them in an arraylist and when all items are iterated through, I then do a `targetProject.addAll(items)`.  I couldn't tell a difference, though.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I'm using Ehcache as a second-level caching.  I'm also still on Hibernate 3.2.5.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code issues too many database queries due to frequent use of `createFilter()`.

It would be better to fetch all needed objects into memory by a few queries, and then perform necessary checks using appropriate in-memory data structures (`Map`s, `Set`s).

Comment: SO, instead of doing to many queries, I can just iterate over the list of items that I retrieve via `targetProject().getItems().iterator()`, then check for duplicate items there?

Comment: @EricV: Yes, basically so. Just make sure that you do it with minimal number of queries, perhaps `join fetch` would help.